# How to use datetime.fromtimestamp() to convert the UTC time format into the correct timezone (a variable)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am building a weather forecast website using the Darksky API (docs: https://darksky.net/dev/docs#forecast-request), and I want to use weather.json()['currently']['timezone'] to convert the Unix time into the timezone given by the city (for example, the input was Mexico City, I want the time in Mexico City) using datetime.fromtimestamp(weather.json()['currently']['timezone']).strftime('-%H'). What more do I need to add? Or what other methods could I try to figure out with?

I tried doing simply

```
Time in {location}: {datetime.fromtimestamp(weather.json()['currently']['time']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}
```

Where location is the city (and yes, it is in an f string)

output was in the UTC time, but I want the time in the timezone (correctly formatted into H:M:S) that the city is in

no error message, just an output I want to manipulate (and I am new to the datetime module)

Answer (score 0):

you can do so in the following way:

```
import datetime
import dateutil.tz as tz
import tzlocal

# dummy datetime in utc for testing    
utc_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

#get current timezone
local_zone = tzlocal.get_localzone().zone

#build timezone information to be removed
utc_zone_info = tz.gettz("UTC")

#build local timezone information to be set
local_zone_info = tz.gettz(local_zone)

#replace utc zone info
replaced_utc = utc_time.replace(tzinfo=utc_zone_info)

#update zone info of datetime object with local timezone
result_dt = replaced_utc.astimezone(tzinfo=local_zone_info).strftime("%H:%m:%S")
```

P.S: You will have to install the tzlocal library via pip/conda